# Invalid HTML5 Input Pattern - Regex

Tags: html, regex, html5-pattern

I'm trying to do validation with HTML form, and i'm getting the following error:

> Pattern attribute value ^(?0( *d)?){10,11}$ is not a valid regular
> expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?0(
> *d)?){10,11}$/: Invalid group

My pattern:

```
^\(?0( *\d\)?){10,11}$
```

When I try this pattern on https://regex101.com/ it shows it as a valid pattern.

Simple preview of what the input looks like:

```
<form>
   <input type="number" pattern="^\(?0( *\d\)?){10,11}$" required="true" />

   <button type="sumbit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Post your form please. We need a [mcve]

Comment: @j08691 updated to show simple preview of the form, it's built in ReactJS so had to quickly just display some of the outputted HTML

Comment: Regex validation with `pattern` does not work with `type="number"`.